# How do I install Oh My Zsh with a custom Zsh install?

Tags: linux, ssh, zsh, oh-my-zsh

So, I've just managed to install zsh on a machine which I have SSH access to (but importantly, no root access to) as per suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293406/install-zsh-without-root-access). I then proceeded to attempt to install Oh My Zsh, and was greeted by this message:

```
Zsh is not installed! Please install zsh first!
```

Which wasn't all that surprising. Upon inspecting the install script, the code for checking if zsh is installed is:

```
CHECK_ZSH_INSTALLED=$(grep /zsh$ /etc/shells | wc -l)
if [ ! $CHECK_ZSH_INSTALLED -ge 1 ]; then
    printf "${YELLOW}Zsh is not installed!${NORMAL} Please install zsh first!\n"
    exit
fi
unset CHECK_ZSH_INSTALLED
```

So, without root access, I cannot edit /etc/shells. It is also possibly important to note that when I SSH into this system, I am not necessarily logging into the same physical machine; rather, I am logged into one of several machines, into which my home directory is copied. Currently I have code in my `.profile` that adds `~/bin` to my `$PATH` and launches zsh upon login.

Essentially, is there any way around this? I assume that the install script can be modified to accommodate zsh being installed to ~/bin/zsh, but just blindly removing the checking logic certainly seems nothing if not ill-advised.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The checking logic is only there to prevent `chsh` from failing at the end of the installation. If your `zsh` binary is not listed in `/etc/shells`, you will be unable to use `chsh` to change your login shell. In that case running `~/bin/zsh` from one of your current login shells startup files is the only way to launch `zsh` automatically. As `~/.profile` is usually only used for login sessions, it should be fine. You might want to run `zsh -l` from there to get a login session instead of just an interactive session (it differs in which configuration files are loaded).

In order to install *oh-my-zsh*, you will have to either strip some of the code from `install.sh`: namely the check mentioned in the question and where it tries to automatically run `chsh`. Or you just run the following two commands:

```sh
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh.git $HOME/.oh-my-zsh
cp $HOME/.oh-my-zsh/templates/zshrc.zsh-template ~/.zshrc
```

Unless you want to install *oh-my-zsh* somewhere other than `~/.oh-my-zsh` nothing else is needed. Everything else in `install.sh` is just:

- safeguards against overwriting an already existing *oh-my-zsh* installation in the same place, which `git clone` would prevent anyway
- backing up `~/.zshrc`, which you probably do not have on a fresh installation
- setting the the login shell, which does not work in your case anyway
- and lots of colorful output.